# Write text on image

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to write a text on an image in java gwt? I know it would be possible by using a Button instead but I need an image for this special problem...

Comment: Please edit the question to improve its quality. Although the meaning of your question was understandable for me, having clearly worded questions is important on Stackoverflow, so people can find questions and their answers easily, and it helps everybody to understand what the actual question was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a Canvas is too complex, you could simply overlay the image with a text div. Position them both absolutely in the same container, both at position [0, 0] relative to that container.

Maybe use a LayoutPanel like

```xml
<ui:style>
  .mypanel {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .myimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .mytext {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
</ui:style>

<g:LayoutPanel addStyleNames="{style.mypanel}">

  <g:layer>
    <g:Image url="my.png" addStyleNames="{style.myimg}"/>
  </g:layer>

  <g:layer>
    <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.mytext}">123</g:Label>
  </g:layer>

</g:LayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the image in a canvas and then draw the text in the same canvas

Comment: I'm not that familiar with canvas and it seems pretty complicated for the thing I'm trying to do, I basically have a grey circle in with I want to draw a number, ain't there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As Roger suggested, canvas gives you a lot of control over an image. You might find of help [the newly announced Lienzo](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/lZJ3bv1UqUU/udfjP1smdmwJ), a structured graphics library for GWT which utilizes canvas.

Check out what Lienzo can do [here](http://www.emitrom-lienzo.appspot.com/).